# What time the cron job will start for the very first time? Does it start immediately?

Tags: cron, cron-task

if i am setting my cronjob to be scheduled for every 30 minutes as:

```
> crontab -e

30 * * * * path/to/file/somecommand
```

What time the cron job will start for the very first time ? Does it start immediately ?

Comment: thats why i am asking

Comment: Please run 'man 5 crontab' on shell.

Comment: It will start at minute 0 and 30 every hour every day, not immediately.